# onClick with foreach css change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop in php with bootstrap collapse panel and I want to know if there is any option to change color of `div.panel-heading` on-click for a single title.

So when I click on first title of `<a href="..."></a>` only the first `div.panel-heading` turns into red background.

```
@foreach($aa as $msg)

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
Sender: <a href="/member-list/{{{$msg->username}}}">{{{$msg->username}}}</a>  
{{{ " title:  ". "  "}}}

<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{{$msg->msg_id}}} ">
{{{$msg->title}}}
</a>

</h4>
</div>

<div id="collapse{{{$msg->msg_id}}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
{{{$msg->msg}}}
</div>

</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this using jquery:

```
    $('div.panel-heading a').click(function(){

    $('div.panel-heading').css('background','transparent');        

    var ParentDiv = $(this).parent();

    ParentDiv.css('background','red');

});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked as I want after I change the $('div.panel-heading a').click(function() to $('div.panel-heading h4').click(function()

Comment: good, yes i gave you idea by putting on a href, you got idea now you can apply on h4 or whatever element in panel-heading. Cheers!

Comment: I just wonder why it is not working with addClass in Jquery?Do you know why? http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/zFxVL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this  (used jquery lib )
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smartyatwork/zFxVL/)

```
 $('div.panel-heading').click(function(){
 $('div.panel-heading').removeClass('bgcolor');
$(this).addClass('bgcolor');
 });
```

Comment: he wants if clicked link change div color, not on div click